# Webpack change the name of functions and clases

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, export, prototype

I am using Webpack to minify my javascript file, but I need the name of my class not to change, since I want to call it to create an object when calling the minified file

**For example:(file.js)**

```
MediumSharer.prototype = {
    constructor: MediumSharer,
    window: window,
    ...
```

**is changed to:(minified.js)**

`r.prototype={constructor:r,window:window,diffLeft:0 ...`

**and when I try to call the constructor does not exist because the name was changed**

```
<script src="./minified.js"></script>
<script>
    let sharer = new MediumSharer()
    sharer.init()
</script>
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/file.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'minified.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you put your code in an inline script? If it'd be part of your bundle, minify/uglify take care of that "issue".

Comment: @naeramarth7  it's a package/library so I want it to be able to be used with a node (via npm) or CDN. I'm testing the independient file.